# How to register HttpHandlers in IIS 7.0 integrated mode using .ashx files

Tags: web-config, httphandler, ashx

According to documents it's clear how to register HttpHandlers in IIS 7.0 integrated mode if you implement `IHttpHandler` inside a dll and put it in `Bin` folder of web application. Then adding a line in `web.config` of that application completes the registeration process.
There is an `.ASHX` file type which implements `IHttpHandler` by default. Since this file is not compiled into dll in Bin folder (and I didn't find where it go after compilation) any try to add correct `type` for it in `web.config` failed for me. `web.config`:

```
<handlers>
   <add name="MyHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="MyHandler, Myhandler"resourceType="unspecified" precondition"integratedmode" />
</handlers>
```

**Question: How to register `HttpHandlers` written in `.ASHX` files ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't register, you just call your ashx-file like a regular aspx, asmx or html file. http://yourweb.com/yourhandler.ashx :)

Comment: I want capture all calls to a virtual directory without anything like a page address in url, i.e: http://localhost/myVirtualDirectory instead of http://localhost/myVirtualDirectory/myHandler.ashx then you say I cannot do that with ashx file and should register a dll ?

Comment: @Xaqron: If that's what you want then it's url rewriting you are looking for :)

Comment: I'm gonna accept everything in URL, this is different from URL rewriting

Comment: Hm, I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to redirect everything to your handler?